# Whats wrong with this varchar2 columns data Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a SELECT statement:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE1 t1,TABLE2 t2 
WHERE t1.tid=t2.tid 
    AND t1.Col21 IN   ('103271','103280','107114','108083','116762','118462','119233','120562','125833','129706')
```

This does not return any data but I do know there are records for all of the above value in Col21.

I have tried trim(Col21) but still no data.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What makes you believe that there is data that matches those values in the table that also satisfies the join criteria?  It's possible that you've hit some obscure situation or bug but it's quite a bit more likely that there is something about the data that isn't what you expect.  If you can show us why you believe the query should return rows, it's a lot more likely that we can figure out what about the data isn't what you expect.

Comment: Are you certain there is data in t2.tid that matches your where condition?

Comment: A data issue for sure, not with the `t1.col IN` but i think things dont match up with `t1.tid=t2.tid`.

Answer (score 1):

First, for peace of mind, verify that there are matching rows in `Col21` with this query.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM TABLE1 t1
 WHERE t1.Col21 IN ('103271','103280','107114','108083','116762','118462',
                    '119233','120562','125833','129706')
```

If that returns rows, then the reason your presented query is not returning anything is due to the join against `TABLE2`.  Perhaps you meant to do an outer join?  If so, try something like this:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM TABLE1 t1,TABLE2 t2 
 WHERE t1.tid=t2.tid(+)
   AND t1.Col21 IN ('103271','103280','107114','108083','116762','118462',
                    '119233','120562','125833','129706')
```

This will allow nulls in `t2.tid` where there is no row in `TABLE2` corresponding to that in `TABLE1`, guaranteeing that all matching rows in `TABLE1` are always returned.